# Switching between layouts and keeping content displayed

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my main layout (mainlayout) I am displaying some text and images which are set dynamically based on the actions of the user. For one particular button click I need to display the contents of another layout (secondlayout). I do this using:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);
```

On the second layout I have another button that I use to return to the main layout, once again using:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
```

The problem is on displaying the mainlayout again all the text and images I was displaying have now disappeared.

How can I return to the mainlayout and still display the contents I was displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't do it that way. `setContentView()` is meant to be called once in your `onCreate()` method. however, couple of reasonable ways to do it,

1. encapsulate each layout in a fragment, then show / hide each fragment as needed.
2. bundle both layouts into a single layout, and show / hide each section of the layout by calling `setVisibility()` on the layout's outermost container.

Comment: Can you please point me to some examples for fragments? Also, I am reluctant to use setVisibility() method as I want to keep the layout information separate so I can use the graphical representation to move stuff about. It would get too confusing if I combined the two.

Comment: I was successful in doing what you suggested by bundling both layouts into a single layout and then doing a setVisibility. However my question about cluttered xml graphical view still stands. I will post a new question on this.

Comment: check out the include tag. you can keep your layout components easily decomposed into reusable pieces. if you need to bundle logic with these pieces, you should look into fragments.